# How to ENABLE VT-x in the BIOS on a desktop remotely?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bios, virtualization, vt-x

I'm accessing a Windows 10 desktop which is situated in office remotely from home. I've installed an OS on Oracle VirtualBox and when I run, I'm getting error of - VT-x is disabled.

```
Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
```

I'm completely aware on what do in BIOS. But unfortunately, I had to enter into BIOS during system boots. I won't be having network connection to enable VT-x (virtualization).

I tried to search Windows command to ENABLE THE VT-x on a remote desktop instead of going into BIOS. I gave up, nothing worked much.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could help with this information to resolve issue of enabling the VT-x on a remote desktop instead of getting into BIOS.

I also understand from the implementation limitations. Of course one could not access Windows desktop during BIOS as system won't be having any network connection, and it's highly impossible to check this kind of question.But if there are any work around still, by enabling VT-x over BIOS commands, then would be good.

Comment: VT-x is only required if you are attempting to use a 64-bit operating system within a virtual machine.  It is not possible to remotely enable VT-x on your office machine.

Comment: there are some solutions to access BIOS setup remotely but they need some special hardware to be installed

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I forgot to mention I was using 64-bit OS. Well, there is no any other option to enable remotely. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @phuclv It's recommended for us not to install any special hardware. Hope, it's quite difficult to access BIOS remotely without any net connection. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @devPython - The solution to your problem for the time being, is to install a 32-bit operating system on the VM, then in the future be sure VT-x is enabled on the machine before you work from home.

Comment: another workaround is to use [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) or [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) to [emulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) a 64-bit VM so you can continue to use later when VT-x is enabled. But emulation is very slow so it'll only suitable if you only use CLI applications that aren't performance sensitive